# USB-C Splitter for Power-in & A/V-out - Does this exist?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, charging, usb-c, splitter

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad laptop that has a single USB-C port (plus a couple of standard USB 3 ports and an HDMI port). The USB-C also happens to be the main charging port for the laptop.

I have a portable monitor, which connects perfectly to my laptop via a USB-C to USB-C cable, and is able to receive both power and A/V input via this connection. However, as the USB-C on my laptop is the only charging port, this means I can't charge my laptop *and* use the monitor at the same time using USB-C alone.

My solution has been to use a USB-C to USB-C/HDMI/USB-A splitter, in the configuration shown in the attached image (below). While this works fine, it's a bit "messy", as it requires two cables going to the monitor (HDMI [for A/V], USB-A [for power]) rather than a single USB-C cable, as is the case when the laptop doesn't require charging.

[USB-C to USB-A/HDMI/USB-C splitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkfRC.jpg)

I have been unable to find a USB-C splitter (male --> 2 x female) that would be suitable for this, however. Most appear to split to power and audio output, which means it wouldn't be suitable for POWER-IN (to charge the laptop) and A/V + POWER-OUT (for the monitor).

**Does such a splitter exist? And, indeed, *can* such a splitter exist, or is this a limitation in the technology (i.e., in terms of power management)?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't a splitter, it is a USB hub.  What you want is a usb C hub that is all usb C.

Comment: How did you fix this? I've just got a lenovo laptop from my job. The HDMI port doesn't seem to support my 3840x1600x75Hz display. So I can now choose either to charge, or to use the display via the one USB-C connector (F$$k Lenovo for only putting one USB-C connector on the laptop.)

Comment: The device you want is a USB-C docking station. It may or may not support video-out and/or power over another USB-C port.

Answer (score 1):

Rokid Hub. They advertise it as charging your Switch while displaying Switch to Rokid Air or Max AR glasses.  I don't know if it will work with laptop or Steam Deck but YouTube video shows reviewer using it with a phone with USB-C display out. Says it's a Display pass-through via USB-C.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Does such a splitter exist?

No.

> can such a splitter exist

No, HDMI will always need an USB client device (as in your picture), and can never be done with a passive splitter.

A/V via USB-C uses so called "alternate modes", and is not the same as HDMI.

You cannot even split USB-C into a "power" USB-C part and a "non-power" USB-C part, because power management is quite complicated, and needs the USB data lines for negotiation.

> is this a limitation in the technology

Well, it works differently from how you think it works. If you want to call this a "limitation" is up to you.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point. What OP wants is very much possible and many Thunderbolt docking stations support it: supply power to the laptop *and* supply power to downstream devices *and* pass along DisplayPort over USB-C. HDMI is merely OP's current workaround.